# Type Error in Sympy Piecwise Python: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, piecewise

i try to create linear function in an interval and the other interval is 0. and add it to an array

so i tried this code

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib as plt  # This is all the library's i need
import mpmath
x = sp.symbols('x')
n = 10
xx = (np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)]))
i = 0
N = []
N[0] = sp.Piecewise( ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), xx[0, i] <= x),
                     ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), x <= xx[0, i + 1]),
                     (0, True)
)
```

and it always returns

```
 line 511, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

EDIT: after i add x is positive to symbol
i try to make a vector of linear function in the intervals in a loop and i don't know why it refuses to determine the the truth value even tough in the line above it succeed:

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib as plt  # This is all the library's i need
import mpmath
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
n = 10
xx = (np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)]))
i = 0
N = []
a = sp.Piecewise(
              ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), (xx[0, i]) <= x),
              ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), (x <= (xx[0, i + 1]))),
              (0, True)
)
N.append(a)
for i in range(1, n):
    a = sp.Piecewise(
        (0, x < xx[0, i - 1]),
        ((xx[0, i - 1] - x) / (xx[0, i - 1] - xx[0, i]), ((xx[0, i - 1]) <= x)),
        ((xx[0, i - 1] - x) / (xx[0, i - 1] - xx[0, i]), (x <= (xx[0, i]))),
        ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), ((xx[0, i]) <= x)),
        ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), (x <= (xx[0, i + 1]))),
        (0, True)
    )
    N.append(a)
```

and i get the same Error:

File "", line 23, in 
File "pythonProjectFEANew\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 511, in **bool**
raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

Comment: Why are you making `xx` a 2d array, with `xx = (np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)]))`.  `xx=np.linspace(0,1,n+1)` is a (n+1,) shape 1d array, that can be indexed as `xx[i]`.  And given the problems with `np.float`, you might want make a list, `xx=xx.tolist()`.  Other than the convenience of using linspace, you aren't really using `numpy` here.  Often using using numpy and sympy together gives problems.

Comment: thank you sir! i didn't think about it. i am new to Python and i still trying to get use to everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in numpy float64 somehow:

```
In [48]: xx[0,1]
Out[48]: 0.1

In [49]: type(xx[0,1])
Out[49]: numpy.float64

In [50]: xx[0,1] < x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError

sympy/core/relational.py in __bool__(self)
    509 
    510     def __bool__(self):
--> 511         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    512 
    513     def _eval_as_set(self):

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

The error comes from sympy but it's because `numpy.float64.__lt__` is for some reason calling `bool` on the inequality that is returned by `x.__gt__`. If you reverse the direction of the inequality or convert the `numpy.float64` to an ordinary Python `float` then it will work fine:

```
In [51]: x > xx[0,1]
Out[51]: x > 0.1

In [52]: float(xx[0,1]) < x
Out[52]: x > 0.1
```

The bug is that `numpy.float64.__lt__` should be returning `NotImplemented` somewhere but instead does something weird.

Comment: I've opened an issue with numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22535

Comment: I add ordinary python float, And reverse the direction of inequality and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a bug.

You can work around it by first converting your numerical value to a `Float`, like this:

```py
sp.Piecewise(
    ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), sp.Float(xx[0, i]) <= x),
    ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), x <= xx[0, i + 1]),
    (0, True)
)
```

Comment: it worked when i add that x is positive
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib as plt  # This is all the library's i need
import mpmath
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
n = 10
xx = (np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)]))
i = 0
N = []
a = sp.Piecewise(
              ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), (xx[0, i]) <= x),
              ((xx[0, i + 1] - x) / (xx[0, i + 1] - xx[0, i]), (x <= (xx[0, i + 1]))),
              (0, True)
)
N.append(a)
a
1.0 - 10.0*x